# Conflicting dependency versions in composer.json

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, guzzle

I must have in my project two 3rd-party dependencies.

I can add them separately, but I cannot add them together, because
the 1st dependency requires guzzlehttp/guzzle version ^7.0, but the 2nd requires ^6.0.

In final I think both of them can work with the 6th or the 7th version, because there should not be much interface differences.

How can I make it work without forking 3rd party and changing the required version?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not use an older version of the one dependency (which currently requires v7), or help the maintainers of the other library to upgrade their code for Guzzle v7?

Answer (score 0):

You can try faking the version of `guzzlehttp/guzzle` by adding it to your `composer.json` with the following:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "7.2.0 as 6.5.5"
```

This should satisfy both dependencies. However, this form of tricks is really not recommended since it goes against semver and there's a high chance that something will break, since, presumably, both of your packages support those specific versions of Guzzle for valid reasons.

Comment: As you can see on https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/UPGRADING.md, there have been numerous breaking changes

Comment: I haven't gone through the specific changes, I've just provided the answer to the question author. It is ultimately his responsibility if this require does not work, as I noted in my answer.